# Comparing same Keys in ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> based off comparison remove element in Array

Tags: java, arrays, hash, arraylist

Below is my current code:

```
private void processData(StringBuffer reportBuffer) {
    String tableName = "db2_table_name";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tableValue = FileData.get(tableName);

    String No = "No";
    String versionNumber = "VersionNumber";


    for (HashMap<String, String> fieldValue : tableValue) {

        String No = fieldValue.get(No);
        String Version = fieldValue.get(versionNumber);

        reportBuffer.append("No is: " + No + " and Version is: " +Version + NL);
    }
}
```

The current output of this is:

```
No is: 1. and Version is: 1.
No is: 1. and Version is: 2.
No is: 3. and Version is: 1.
No is: 3. and Version is: 2.
No is: 3. and Version is: 3.
```

What I am looking to do is only keep the latest version of each No while removing the element of the older versions. So within my new ArrayList I would ideally want to only have:

```
No is: 1. and Version is: 2.
No is: 3. and Version is: 3
```

Let me know if you need any clarifications!

Thanks!
.

Comment: These versions are across different maps right? What do you exactly want to do? what are you trying to achieve? Why List of Maps?

Comment: yes they are across different maps, each row above is its own map. I process the output and only want to process the latest version so the previous versions of the same No 1 are not useful to me.

Comment: List of maps because there are actually multiple table_name's not only db2_table_name but I'm only concerned about this one

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new HashMap and save the latest version for each No inside that hashmap.
You should be able to do that by saving each No and Version in the hashmap while you go through the for loop you have there. However, every time before you save a value, you should check if the hashmap contains the current No, and if yes don't save it but check if the stored version is smaller than the current one and replace it.

At the end, create a loop to go around the hashmap and use it along with the reportBuffer.append()

Comment: Yeah I was thinking something similar..how would you incorporate deleting of the elements of the array? so what remains of my arrayList is only the latest versions? The only reason I am asking this is because the Map actually contains a lot of other key,value pairs not just No,Version.

Comment: You could create a new ArrayList of HashMaps and follow the procedure I described earlier. So, at the end you will have a new ArrayList of HashMaps with the latest versions only. So then you can completely remove/ignore the first ArrayList.

Comment: The other way (if you wish to keep the same ArrayList) is to keep in a Vector/Array the indexes of Objects (HashMaps) in the ArrayList that have smaller versions and using the ArrayList remove(index) method to delete all the unnecessary elements at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Heres one way

Keep a  `Map<String,Integer> lowestAmongMaps = new HashMap<String,Integer>();`

In your for loop, add the lowest value for each key to this map..
basically, something like this

```
Integer currentLowest = Integer.valueOf(lowestAmongMaps.get(versionNumber));
            if(currentLowest == null){
                currentLowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }
            Integer currentVal = Integer.valueOf(Version).intValue();
            if( currentVal.intValue() < currentLowest.intValue()){
                lowestAmongMaps.put(versionNumber,currentVal);
            }
```

Now in the next iteration remove all keys which are not lowest.

So basically you have two iterations over

```
for (HashMap<String, String> fieldValue : tableValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

If its a database the best way would be to modify the query to return only max version from FileData.get(). But I suppose its a file. So a simple solution would be to keep a third map to store the report values. Eg

```
private void processData(StringBuffer reportBuffer) {
    String tableName = "db2_table_name";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tableValue = FileData.get(tableName);

    String no = "No";
    String versionNumber = "VersionNumber";

    Map<String, String> mergedMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (HashMap<String, String> fieldValue : tableValue) {

        String No = fieldValue.get(no);
        String Version = fieldValue.get(versionNumber);

        if(mergedMap.containsKey(No)){
            Integer previousVersion = Integer.valueOf(mergedMap.get(No));
            Integer currentVersion = Integer.valueOf(Version);
            if(currentVersion > previousVersion){
                mergedMap.put(No, Version);
            }
        } else {
            mergedMap.put(No, Version);
        }
    }

    for(Entry<String, String> entry : mergedMap.entrySet()){
        reportBuffer.append("No is: " + entry.getKey() + " and Version is: " + entry.getValue() + NL);
    }
}
```